# Chrome native messaging host in golang fails when JSON size is more than 65500 characters

Tags: json, go, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to write a native messaging host for chrome in golang. For this purpose, I tried using [chrome-go](https://github.com/lhside/chrome-go) as well as [chrome-native-messaging](https://github.com/jdiamond/chrome-native-messaging) packages. Both presented with the same problem as explained below.

Here is the code. I have added the relevant parts from the [chrome-go](https://github.com/lhside/chrome-go) package to the main file instead of importing it for easy understanding.

The following code actually works when I send a json message to it like {content:"Apple Mango"}. However, it stops working once the length of the json goes over approximately 65500 characters, give or take a 100 characters. There is no error output either.

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/binary"
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "io"
  "os"
)

var byteOrder binary.ByteOrder = binary.LittleEndian

func Receive(reader io.Reader) ([]byte, error) {
   // Read message length in native byte order
   var length uint32
   if err := binary.Read(reader, byteOrder, &length); err != nil {
       return nil, err
   }

// Return if no message
if length == 0 {
    return nil, nil
}

// Read message body
received := make([]byte, length)
if n, err := reader.Read(received); err != nil || n != len(received) {
    return nil, err
}
return received, nil
}

type response struct {
    Content string `json:"content"`
}

func main() {

  msg, err := Receive(os.Stdin)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  var res response
  err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(msg), &res)
  if err != nil {
     panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(res.Content)
 }
```

For those interested in testing, I have set up a repository with instructions. Run the following

```
  git clone --depth=1  https://tesseract-index@bitbucket.org/tesseract-index/chrome-native-messaging-test-riz.git && cd chrome-native-messaging-test-riz
 ./json2msg.js < test-working.json | go run main.go
 ./json2msg.js < test-not-working.json | go run main.go
```

You will see that `test-not-working.json` gives no output, although its difference with `test-working.json` is a few hundred characters only.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Based on Alex's response, perhaps you can compress the json stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limitation of a pipe buffer which varies across systems. Mac OS X, for example, uses a capacity of 16384 bytes by default.

You can use this bash script to check your buffer capacity:

```
M=0; while printf A; do >&2 printf "\r$((++M)) B"; done | sleep 999
```

So it is not related to go, because I tried to change your code to read from file and Unmarshal and it worked:

```
func main() {
    reader, err := os.Open("test-not-working.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var res response
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(reader)
    err = decoder.Decode(&res)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(res.Content)
}
```

Comment: That sounds right. The pipe buffer limitation in my system is 65536. I have marked your answer as accepted. However if you could modify it with the information on how to overcome this, that would be awesome.

PS: It is also worth mentioning that a [native host written in python](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/native-messaging/app/ping_pong.py) does not have the same limitation somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the pipe buffer of your OS is limited to 65536 bytes. Thus, the `os.Stdin.Read(...)` function can read 65536 bytes at once.

You can fix your code with this simple replacement:

```
n, err := io.ReadFull(reader, received)
```

And there is your error:

```
msg, err := Receive(os.Stdin)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

You have compared `err` with `nil`, but you have not compared `msg` with `nil`. But since you have read 65532 (`65536 - 4`) bytes, the `func Receive(...)` returned `nil, nil`.

To fix this, your function `Receive(...)` ought not return `nil, nil`.